# Get an array of category ids in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$cats=  get_categories(array(
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                  => 'id',

    'hierarchical'             => 0,
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'taxonomy'                 => 'edu_year'
));
```

I would like to produce a variable that contains an array of the IDs of the values retrieved from the get_categories function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the documentation it returns:

```
$category->term_id
$category->name
$category->slug
$category->term_group
$category->term_taxonomy_id
$category->taxonomy
$category->description
$category->parent
$category->count
$category->cat_ID
$category->category_count
$category->category_description
$category->cat_name
$category->category_nicename
$category->category_parent
```

So:

```
$output_categories = array();
$categories=get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
     $output_categories[$category->cat_ID] = $category->name;
}
```

Then `$output_categories` is exactly what you need.

Comment: I would like to have a variable that contains $variable = array(3,4,5) where 3, 4, 5 are the ids of the categories retrieved

Comment: so then just do $output_categories[] = $category->cat_ID;

Answer (score 4):

When you use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms):

```
<?php

$categories_ids = get_terms(
    array( 'category' ), // Taxonomies
    array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) // Fields
);

?>
```

Comment: I find  get_terms('category' array( 'fields' => 'id=>slug' ));  even more useful.