# WordPress: "fake" offset in get_categories?

Tags: wordpress, offset

i use the following code to generate a list of categories. Sometimes there are more then 10 categories. In this case I want to split the list and show a link to collapse the list.

```
<ul>
<?php $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args=array('hide_empty' => '0', 'taxonomy' => 'tax', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'offset' => '10' );
                $categories=get_categories($args);
                foreach($categories as $category) {
                    echo '<li class="list-group-item '.$category->slug.'';
                    if ($category->slug == $term->slug) :
                        echo ' active';
                    endif;
                    echo '"><a href="/'.$category->slug.'/" title="'.$category->name.'">' . $category->name.'</a><span class="badge">' . $category->count.' </span></li>';} ?>
            </ul>
```

As I know, there is no offset in get_categories. Is there any way to "fake" an offset or add something after 10 categories?

Comment: Put an iterator in your `foreach` to count the categories, then test for if it's more than 10 and change code accordingly.

Comment: I tried my best but i can't work it out. can you please give me a code example?

Comment: does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790371/1788961

I have two lists and exclude the IDs from the first list in the second. Works fine